# Processing $ zero amount transaction

Tags: authorize.net

I want to validate phone number associated with credit card number during transaction processing using authorize.net. i.e I want to check entered phone number is same as that of credit card issuing bank's record during transaction processing with authorize.net.

If entered phone number is valid & is same with phone number that is associated with credit card then only I can proceed for real transaction processing other wise I will not pass transaction to authorize.net payment gateway.

Can I use `auth_only` transaction type i.e  (`x_type= "Auth_only"`)  with $0.0 amount for authorizing request to validate entered  phone number with phone number associated with credit card ?

Does card get charged any way or it is get reflected in card statement  when  we authorize only $0.0 transaction. ?

I do not want to charge card any way or transaction to be displayed in customers statement after authorizing only transaction (`x_type= "Auth_only"`)

Please kindly help how to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate phone number associated with credit card in authorize.net in asp.net (c#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349033/validate-phone-number-associated-with-credit-card-in-authorize-net-in-asp-net-c)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to validate a phone number is associated with a credit card because *there is no such thing as a phone number being associated with a credit card*. A credit card will have a Card number, expiration date, CVV, and billing address. It does *not* have a phone number associated with it. Additionally, phone numbers are not sent to the card issuing bank so even if there was one, it can't be validated anyway.

Comment: Happy Christmas *Marvin*, hope you have a great time :)